# Is the app with Angular UI template too slow by your side also?

Tags: abp

I'm new in abp angular template.

Is the app with Angular UI template  too slow by your side also? Do I go wrong somehow? I just installed the template, thats all. And app is too slow. Thank you.

### edit:

I've checked the issue using chrome peformance tool and TTFB is almost 1 minute..

[image: ttfb]

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I am sorry. Don't forget to install Redis server. Everything is great now after installing Redis